# Group multiple rows together in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two columns:

```
 - PAGE NAME
 - VALUE
```

The pages are associated with various Categories, i.e.

```
Category 1 = Page 1, Page 5, Page 9
Category 2 = Page 3, Page 4, Page 6
Category 3 = Page 7, Page 8, Page 2
```

How do I group multiple pages together so I can select them in a visual filter? i.e. When I create a new table or graph I can select Category 1 instead of the selecting the individual page names.

I would prefer not to use SUM or AVERAGE as I want to reuse the grouping of page names for various calculations.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a calculated `Category` column along these lines:

```
Category =
SWITCH (
    Table[PageName],
    "Page 1", "Category 1",
    "Page 2", "Category 3",
    "Page 3", "Category 2",
    "Page 4", "Category 2",
    "Page 5", "Category 1",
    "Page 6", "Category 2",
    "Page 7", "Category 3",
    "Page 8", "Category 3",
    "Page 9", "Category 1"
)
```

or like this

```
Category =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    Table[PageName] IN { "Page 1", "Page 5", "Page 9" }, "Category 1",
    Table[PageName] IN { "Page 3", "Page 4", "Page 6" }, "Category 2",
    Table[PageName] IN { "Page 7", "Page 8", "Page 2" }, "Category 3"
)
```